# Import term set with labels

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, term-store, term, term-set

If I'm importing a term set in the terms store with the CSV file how could I include labels to the terms?

I've tried to find information about this but all that i've found is the simplest format:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot import labels using OOB import functionality. I recommend using Lapointe.SharePoint.PowerShell.wsp found [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2012/03/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-2010-terms/) and [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/) to do the import. It supports also labels.

You can do first an export to get sample XML out, then modify it, and finally do import. It will not overwrite existing terms (will throw error), so you need want to remove old items before doing import.